# How to get the most recent files in zipArchive in c#

Tags: c#, .net, filter, zip, c#-ziparchive

I want to get the most recent files from a zipArchive.
Example : I have in my zipArchive three files

```
file1_2022-06-20_2022-06-20_10-20-32
file1_2022-06-20_2022-06-20_10-30-50
file2_2022-06-20_2022-06-20_14-10-20
```

The first thing is the pattern of the file (file1, file2,...);

The second is the creation date;

The third is the modification date and the last is the creation time (HHmmss)

As the most recent file between files (1) is file1_2022-06-20_2022-06-20_10-30-50, result here should be :

```
file1_2022-06-20_2022-06-20_10-30-50
file2_2022-06-20_2022-06-20_14-10-20
```

> I try this:
>
> ```
>     private void FindMostRecentFilesFromZip(string zipPath, string destPath)
>     {
>         using (var zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
>         {
>             var matchesFiles = new List<ZipArchiveEntry>();
>
>             foreach (var entry in zipArchive.Entries)
>             {
>                 if (entry.Name.StartsWith(pattern))
>                 {
>                     matchesFiles .Add(entry);
>               }
>             }
>           // how to get only the most recent files here???
>           var mostRecentFiles = matchesFiles.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime);
>           
>           //here all three files are returned, while the result should only contains two files as explained above
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: I would think you'd have to parse the datetime out of the filenames and then order the entries by the parsed datetime.

Comment: `var mostRecentFile = matchesFiles.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault();` maybe? Although there are more efficient methods, especially considering you have a `foreach` anyway.

Comment: No, the FirstOrDefault will return just one file instead of two